# Java Properties property value - message with leading white space

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I have messages in properties file and reading these properties file using spring and spring message tag,

For example I have :

```
key.red=Red<br>
key.blue=  blue
```

blue message text coming as "blue" but not as "  blue". The leading white spaces are taken out by spring:message tag.

how could i retain leading space ? 
I appreciate any help

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: This is the correct functionality of a Java properties file.  Specifically, the spaces before and after the equal sign are ignored.

Answer (score 15):

Try doing it like this:

```
key.blue=\u0020blue
```

You can use other unicode codes to escape characters as well. All per [Java API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29).
Quote:

> ...Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding can
>   be written using Unicode escapes ....

Comment: this is good, unless you use eclipse editor which on reopening converts \u0020 to ordinary space, then it get ignored, so basically you need to convert those back to \u020 on every file save

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse "smart" editor which converts \u020 back to normal space on prop file reopening/save you do better with "\ " syntax